# expression block type is valid // Stack overflow

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, char, copy-constructor

trying to build a project in C++ For my college.
trying to use my methods i created for MyDate in my Main.cpp
and it keeps getting me stack o/f's and "expression block type is valid " errors.

main.cpp :

```
date1.setDay(8);
date1.setMonth(4);
date1.setYear(1994);
date1.setCmnt("Bday");      //problem with chars and pointers..
date1.print();
//Copy Constructor
date2 = date1;
date2.print();
```

MyDate.h :

```
void setCmnt(char *cmnt){
    if (cmnt!=nullptr)
        *c = *cmnt;
};
```

Copy Const :

```
day=Date.day;
month=Date.month;
year=Date.year;
if (Date.c != nullptr)
{
    c = new char[strlen(Date.c) + 1];
    strcpy(c, Date.c);
    //*c = *Date.c;
}
```

tnx alot for your help guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `Date::setCmnt` as you defined it in MyDate.h only replaces the first character of `Date::c` with the first character of the input string `cmnt`, not the whole string. Probably `Date::c` isn't even initialized, so you're overwriting some random memory here.

I strongly recommend to use `std::string` for handling strings. However, you're pointing out, that this is for college and perhaps you haven't been introduced to `std::string` yet or it's for academic reasons that you're supposed to work with `char*` here. Therefore I'll go with `char*` in this answer:

In your `Date::setCmnt` function you need to copy the string as you do in the copy c'tor. Also if `Date::c` is already assigned a value (`!=nullptr`) you should invoke `delete[]` on it first so you don't create memory leaks. You also need to guarantee that `Date::c` is initialized properly (e.g. to `nullptr`) in every constructor of your class.

E.g.:

```
void setCmnt(char *cmnt){
    if (c!=nullptr)
        delete[] c;
    if (cmnt!=nullptr){
        c = new char[strlen(cmnt) + 1];
        strcpy(c, cmnt);
    }
    else c = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: First of all , I have to say a huge thank you for helping me with my code ,
second - yes i know string , but i have to use char*.

also - really great improvments i've learned alot from that! thanks!
and lastly - my bug still buggin me :(
pic ;  http://tinypic.com/r/2n87czr/8

Comment: This might mean, that you're deleting a pointer which is already deleted. Also make sure you're not storing pointers/references to any temporary objects.

Comment: You were right!
i went to my destructor and that was the problem , 

{ if (c!=nullptr) delete[] c;}

what should i do to fix it ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You probably have not initialized `c` in your constructor. Therefore it has some random, invalid contents. Testing for `c!=nullptr` returns `false` leading to `delete[] c`, where `c` has never been allocated before. Simply make sure that `c` is initialized to `nullptr` in your constructor and you should be fine.

Comment: In my above comment I meant: Testing for `c!=nullptr` returns `true`. Mixed that up...